# Will the Access keys used by services will be affected by moving resources to another subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

**Issue:** I am planning to move my Azure Resources to another subscription but as an impact analysis I want to know if **Access Keys** to a resource such as *Storage, Batch Services* will be affected.

I have more than 30 services which are currently in use. I am looking forward to having least possible **downtime** and so I need to analyze what all services will be impacted.

I am aware of the resources which are possible to migrate from the Microsoft page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources.

Here are my few questions, I would like to know the answers in all possible cases such as migration to different *directory/Azure Active directory* or common *Azure Active directory*.

1. Will the **Access Keys** to a resource such as Storage, Batch Services etc.. will be affected after I migrate my resource to another subscription?
2. Do I need to reconfigure the **Service Endpoints**?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't do this test because I don't have multiple subscriptions in one tenant. You can create a free storage account and move it ot another subscription first to check if the Access keys will be affected. But I think that the Access keys won't be changed.:-)

Comment: Even I am holding the assumption that they won't change, thanks for the quick reply but even I do have only one subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. They wont change
2. No, storage account endpoints are not tied to resourceId